# Tkinter - unable to place button on middle Canvas/Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Could someone help me to solve the issue that I have in Tkinter?

I want to create three frames/canvas one below the each other. Once I placed any widgets(buttons/labels) on the middle canvas the position of the canvas moved down.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class GameMain:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        top_bg = tk.PhotoImage(file="TopFrame.png")

        root.geometry("1280x900+3+3")
        cv=tk.Canvas(root,width=1280,height=100)
        cv.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="yes")
        cv.create_image(0,0,image=top_bg,anchor='nw')
        Btn1 = tk.Button(cv,text="button1")
        Btn1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        Btn2 = tk.Button(cv,text="Button2")
        Btn2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        mcv=tk.Canvas(root,width=1280,height=700,bg="red",border=1)
        mcv.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="yes")
        #Once I placed the following button, middle canvas moved down and shows empty spaces lot
        Btn3 = tk.Button(mcv,text="button1")
        Btn3.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
        Btn4 = tk.Button(mcv,text="Button2")
        Btn4.pack(padx=5,pady=5)

        bcv=tk.Canvas(root,width=1280,height=100,bg="yellow")
        bcv.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="yes")

        root.mainloop()

GameMain()
```

Comment: Are you wanting these three canvases to remain exactly the height you give them?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for any widget is to expand or contract to exactly fit all of its children widgets. In my experience, this behavior gives you the most flexible UI with the least amount of work. This feature is called "geometry propagation".

If you want to force a container widget to be a specific size, you can give it a size and then turn geometry propagation off. For example, you could add this line of code:

```
mcv.pack_propagate(False)
```

However, to truly force a widget to a specific size requires more work because it is dependent on how *it* is added to *its* parent. It's actually quite rare in UI design to want a widget to be a very specific size regardless of what is inside the widget.

More often than not, there are better solutions to your problem. For example, you're setting your window to a height of 900, with two 100 pixel tall windows and a 700 pixel tall window. By simply forcing the middle window to take up any extra space (along with having the other windows *not* take up extra space), you can get the same effect without having to turn geometry propagation off.

Without knowing the exact look and behavior you want to achieve, it's difficult to make a specific recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason for this issue is a bit puzzling; something about adding buttons to the canvas is making its geometry change.  A workaround to this problem is to force the canvas to stay at least 700 pixels tall (kind of like wedging a stick in a door to keep it open).  To do this, I added a `frame` to one side of the canvas and gave it a padding of `pady=350`.  Why 350?  Because it will pad 350 pixels above and below (thus adding up to 700).  As long as you don't add anything to the frame, it will remain invisible.  Here is a working example for you:

```
mcv=tk.Canvas(root,width=1280,height=700,bg="red",border=1)
mcv.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="yes")
frame = tk.Frame(mcv)  # Add this frame to your canvas.
frame.pack(side="left", anchor="nw", pady=350)
Btn3 = tk.Button(mcv,text="button1")
Btn3.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
Btn4 = tk.Button(mcv,text="Button2")
Btn4.pack(padx=5,pady=5)
```

Comment: _"something about adding buttons to the canvas is making its geometry change"_: that "something" isn't puzzling at all. That is the default behavior for any tkinter widget -- when you use `pack` or `grid` to manage internal widgets, the containing widget "shrinks to fit".